# Formating a phone number string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, format

I was wondering if there is a simpler way in MySQL to take a 10 digit phone number `9876543210` and display it in the format `(987) 654-3210`. I have code that works fine but I was wondering if there was another way perhaps similar to `DATE_FORMAT()`.

The code I'm using:

```
IF(phone_cell != '',
    CONCAT('(',
            SUBSTRING(phone_cell, 1, 3),
            ') ',
            SUBSTRING(phone_cell, 4, 3),
            '-',
            SUBSTRING(phone_cell, 7, 4)),
    '') AS Mobile
```

The part I'm seeking is to replace the `CONCAT` statement.

Comment: FWIW: Your code only "works fine" for NANP (USA/Canada/Caribbean) phone numbers. International numbers use numerous other formats…

Comment: Good point. The majority of numbers in my list, however, will be local U.S. numbers so this isn't really that big of a problem. If it does become a problem I can deal with it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No. Unfortunately, there is no such method as to format the phone number in MySQL.
Your `concat` method is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`INSERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_insert):

```
SELECT INSERT(INSERT(INSERT(s.num,1,0, '('), 5,0,') '),10,0,'-')
FROM (SELECT '9876543210' AS num) s;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=46aa18494453f359acf87fc6beb14266)**